# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los eventos de Google Analytics en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, google-analytics

Estoy intentando obtener los eventos que tengo creados en GA pero por mucho que haya buscado en foros no he conseguido nada, si alguien podría echarme una mano o iluminarme.

Con este código si que obtengo resultados pero ahora quiero obtener de los eventos que he creado, como por ejemplo click a una imagen, entre otros.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Analytics;
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;

class TestAnalytics extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        // recupera visitantes y datos de páginas vistas para el día actual y los últimos siete días
        //Retrieve Most Visited Pages
        $pages = Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages(Period::days(1));

        //retrieve visitors and pageview data for the current day and the last fifteen days
        $visitors = Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(15));

        // Retrieve Total Visitors and Page Views
        $total_visitors = Analytics::fetchTotalVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));

        // Retrieve Top Referrers
        $top_referrers = Analytics::fetchTopReferrers(Period::days(7));

        // Retrieve User Types
        $user_types = Analytics::fetchUserTypes(Period::days(7));

        //Retrieve Top Browsers
        $top_browser = Analytics::fetchTopBrowsers(Period::days(7));

        $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(
            Period::days(7),
                'ga:sessions',
                [
                    'metrics' => 'ga:sessions, ga:pageviews',
                    'dimensions' => 'ga:yearMonth'
                ]
        );
        /* $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(
            Period::days(7),
            'ga:sessions',
            [
                'ids' => 'ga:210519038',
                'metrics' => 'ga:sessions, ga:avgSessionDuration',
                'dimensions' => 'ga:dimension1'
            ]
        ); */
        $analytics = array();

        foreach($analyticsData['rows'] as $key => $resultado) {
            $analytics[$resultado[0]]=array('visitas'=>$resultado[1], 'tiempo_medio'=>$resultado[2]);
        }
        dd($analytics, $pages, $visitors, $total_visitors, $top_referrers, $user_types, $top_browser);//Mostrar datos

    }
}
```

Obtengo los resultado que he encontrado en una web pero tan solo permitia mostrar estos parametros en concreto, cómo sería posible obtener lo que estoy buscando, que son los eventos que he creado?

Debo comentar que estoy usando como herramienta este github https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics

Comment: Con `Analytics::performQuery` prueba seteando las dimensiones a:
`ga:eventCategory, ga:eventAction, ga:eventLabel`
Y luego filtrando por ejemplo, por la categoría del evento: `'filters' =>
'ga:eventCategory==laCategoriaDeTuEvento'`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ He añadido lo siguiente, siguiendo tu comentario. `$events = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days(7),'ga:sessions',['metrics' => 'ga:totalEvents','dimensions' => 'ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel']);`
Y realmente ha funcionado he obtenido los datos que deseaba, pero no lo estoy filtrando ya que deseo tenerlos todos. Aunque he puesto que el periodo sea de 7 días y comparando con la cuenta de GA no coinciden.. por 2 o 3 numeros más. Gracias de antemano, pondré la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cómo solucion para obtener los datos de mi pregunta y por supuesto mil gracias a @porloscerros Ψ.
Este es el código que se ha utilizado:

```
$events = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::days(7),
    'ga:sessions',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:totalEvents',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel'
    ]
);
```

Libreria: github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/master/README.md

Documentacion GA: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por editar la respuesta. Quería comunicarte que cuando te he comentario que había cierta variación respecto a los datos obtenidos, estos son correctos ya que desde GA no había puesto la fecha correctamente, por ejemplo en personalizado añadia ultimos 7 que este no contaba con el día de hoy, por lo tanto obtenia 16 y si añadia 19 (del 12 al 19 de este mes) entonces obtenia un resultado efectivo. Gracias nuevamente compañero!!